# First time using pickle.dump / pickle.load

Tags: python, neural-network, pickle, music21

I'm using a function and at the end of it, it  dumps data in a pickle file, I call my function later on and it works fine. Instead of calling the function, I want to use the data I created. I tried using pickle.load but it doesn't seem to work.

The function:

```
def get_notes():
""" Get all the notes and chords from the midi files in the directory """
notes = []

for file in midi_files:
    midi = converter.parse(file)

    print("Parsing %s" % file)

    notes_to_parse = None

    try:  # file has instrument parts
        s2 = instrument.partitionByInstrument(midi)
        notes_to_parse = s2.parts[0].recurse()
    except:  # file has notes in a flat structure
        notes_to_parse = midi.flat.notes

    for element in notes_to_parse:
        if isinstance(element, note.Note):
            notes.append(str(element.pitch))
        elif isinstance(element, chord.Chord):
            notes.append('.'.join(str(n) for n in element.normalOrder))

with open('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/notes', 'wb') as filepath:
    pickle.dump(notes, filepath)

return notes
```

The second function normally goes like this:

```
def train_network():
""" Train a Neural Network to generate music """
notes = get_notes()

# get amount of pitch names
n_vocab = len(set(notes))

network_input, network_output = prepare_sequences(notes, n_vocab)

model = create_network(network_input, n_vocab)

train(model, network_input, network_output)
```

But I don't want to reparse the files every time I train, I need something like:

```
def train_network():
""" Train a Neural Network to generate music """
notes = pikle.load('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/notes')

# get amount of pitch names
n_vocab = len(set(notes))

network_input, network_output = prepare_sequences(notes, n_vocab)

model = create_network(network_input, n_vocab)

train(model, network_input, network_output)
```

Comment: what does it do when "it doesn't seem to work"? Is there an error?

Comment: `pickle.load` takes a file *object* not a file *path*, just like `pickle.dump`.  Read the documentation :)

Comment: v.7 of music21 should come out this summer or fall, and it will have better parsing of MIDI files so that you don't have to call `instrument.partitionByInstrument` -- that's probably the bottleneck. music21 already tries to help you out by pickling the result of `converter.parse` -- if you dig, you'll see you have to affirmatively send the argument `forceSource=False` to `converter.parse` to get it to NOT load the pickled result from disk.

Answer (score 2):

As @MarkTolonen has also mentioned, `pickle.load` doesn't take file path rather takes an object from the opened file. Try this:

```
with open('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/notes', mode) as f:
    notes = pickle.load(f)
```

You can find more [here](https://pythontic.com/modules/pickle/load) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).